# Problems to cancel numericUpDown with Esc (27) key C#

Tags: c#, winforms, event-handling, keypress, numericupdown

I have a winform application with an access database. 
The form has an numericUpDown to change a value. The only way to cancel te change is to use a cancelbutton or to press esc. Because when the user presses enter/ a confirmbutton or 
changes cells an UpdateCell() function is called:

```
    dtpGridEdit.Validating += (s, e) => { UpdateCell(); };
            comboBoxGridEdit.Validating += (s, e) => { UpdateCell(); };
            textBoxGridEdit.Validating += (s, e) => { UpdateCell(); };
            numericUpDown1.Validating += (s, e) => { UpdateCell(); };

            //CancelButton: 
            buttonGridCancel.Click += (s, e) => { CancelCell(); };

textBoxGridEdit.KeyPress += (s, e) =>
            {
                if (e.KeyChar == (char)13)  // enter in update textbox
                {
                    e.Handled = true;   // eat the enter in this multilinebox
                    UpdateCell();
                }

                if (e.KeyChar == (char)27)  // cancel (Escape) in update textbox
                {
                    CancelCell();
                }
            };

           numericUpDown1.KeyPress += (s, e) =>
            {
                numericUpDown1.Focus(); 

                if (e.KeyChar == (char)13)  // enter in update numericUpDown
                {
                    e.Handled = true;
                    UpdateCell();
                }

                if (e.KeyChar == (char)27)  // cancel (Escape) in update numericUpDown
                {
                    e.Handled = true;
                    CancelCell();
                }
            };
```

etc

If the user used the arrows of the numericUpDown it works. 
If the user used the textbox from the numericUpDown it works with the 
cancelbutton but it doesn't work with the press esc function.

In the other situations such as dataGrid/ ComboBox/ TextBox it works in any way. 
The problem is in only in the combination between the textbox in the NumerbicUpDown and the esc key.press function but I searched everywhere 
and I cannot find a sollution (I'm a newby in programming)

Comment: Probably esc is working by default on numericupdown control and your esc handling code is not executed. Do breakpoint hit KeyPress event handler of numericupdown while debugging?

Comment: That is the strange thing when I'm debugging the breakpoint hit the KeyPress event and so my Cancelfunction and it works so the value DOES change back to the old value. When I stop debugging/remove breakpoint it stops working. I just tested it with a senior programmer and he couldn't give me an explanation for this behaviour

Comment: So whats next? Do your if condition is good? Do CancelCell is executed?

Comment: When I'm debugging/ placed a breakpoint the KeyPress works, so he executes the CancelCell function and it works. When I stop debugging it stop working. Can't figure out the reason why.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.causesvalidation%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: Cannot make it work with CausesValidation either. I think I need the problem somewhere in FOCUS. Whatever I do (debug/breakpoint/print message or even just click on other tab (outside application nothing to do with application) and than it does work, but I still don't know how to fix it.

Comment: Changed it a little bit: with ` numericUpDown1.Focus();` it works! 
I found this because of my previous comment that it did work with breakpoints and messagesboxes.